# How to remove SPACE in Ucrustify's "tab tab SPACE" - indentation?

Tags: c++, uncrustify, code-formatting

My source code

```
namespace one { namespace two {
->  static const class Example :
->  ->  Int1, Int2, Int3
->  {
->  public:
->  Example::~Example() :
->  ->  S1(),
->  ->  S2(),
->  ->  S3() {
->  ->  // if statements with empty braces
->  ->  if ( x )
->  ->  {
->  ->  }
->  ->  }
->  }
->  }
} } //namespace one::two
```

Is processed by Uncrustify to be ("+" = SPACE)

```
namespace one { namespace two {
->  +static const class Example :
->  ->  +Int1, Int2, Int3
->  +{
->  +public:
->  +Example::~Example() :
->  ->  +S1(),
->  ->  +S2(),
->  ->  +S3() {
->  ->  +// if statements with empty braces
->  ->  +if ( x )
->  ->  +{
->  ->  +}
->  ->  +}
->  +}
->  +}
} } //namespace one::two
```

**It always adds a space ("+") after the TAB-indentation.**

Where can I configure this?

Best,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason myself...

Uncrustify doesn't handle the

```
namespace one { namespace two {
```

correctly if both are defined on the same line. When I'm changing that to

```
namespace one { 
namespace two {
```

then it works fine and no space is inserted!